# over writing mangedObjectContext - data dissapearing

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

The setup is this:

- I have  a table view that populates with two different sets of data from two different methods located in the same class.
- When I run the first set of data by itself, it works great.
- When I instantiate the second method that is suppose to grab data based on an ID within the first set of data which is pulled with each loop of the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" , it breaks as if I tried to call on data that no longer exists.

If feels like somewhere in the process the first data set is being replaced by the second data set.

So, the below works.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData

class LendersViewController: UIViewController {

var lenders = Array<Lenders>()
let lendersModel = LendersModel()

//MARK: VC Delegate Methods
override func viewDidLoad() {


    // Get the data from CoreData and Put it into a variable that I can get to later.
    self.lenders = lendersModel.readLenderData() as Array

}


}

extension LendersViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //return lenderData.count!
    return self.lenders.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{



    // Set the cell to reference the LendersViewCell class below.
    //  This contains all the connections to the cell.
    let cell: LendersViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("LenderCell") as LendersViewCell
    let lendersNSArray = lenders as NSArray

    cell.cellLenderName.text = lendersNSArray[indexPath.row].valueForKey("corpName") as String?

    return cell
}
}


class LendersViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var cellLenderLogo: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var cellAprValue: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cellDownValue: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cellMonthlyValue: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var cellFavButtonLabel: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var cellLenderName: UILabel!
}
```

But as soon as I modify the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" with the below, which calls on the second method for its data set, into cellForRowAtIndexPath ...

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{



    // Set the cell to reference the LendersViewCell class below.
    //  This contains all the connections to the cell.
    let cell: LendersViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("LenderCell") as LendersViewCell
    let lendersNSArray = lenders as NSArray

    cell.cellLenderName.text = lendersNSArray[indexPath.row].valueForKey("corpName") as String?

//Adding the below two lines causes an error.
var getLenderId = lendersNSArray[indexPath.row].valueForKey("lenderId") as? String
    self.lenderUserComments = lendersModel.readUserCommentsData(getLenderId!)

    return cell
}
```

The first iteration works but the second iteration throws this error.

```
"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
```

The error here isn't the problem though.  I get that the value "getLenderId" is nil and unwrapping it as nil is throwing the error.

The problem is that the data set from the first method disappears after I instantiate the second method.

Couple points.

1. Both methods are in the same class but read data from two different Core data tables.
2. I am using NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate in that class and that is how the data is manages prior to sending it as an array to the processes making the request.

I searched the site but came across lots of unrelated topics.  I am sure that someone has run into this before so if this has been asked with greater clarity a link to the better question would be appreciated.

Thanks all,

p.s. Here is the model class with the methods that are being called.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData
import UIKit

class LendersModel:NSObject, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate{


//MARK: - Variables
// *** Setup the params used to work with the database.
private let entityName:String = "LenderUserComments"
private let entityName2:String = "Lenders"
private let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate


//Reads ALL lender data
func readLenderData()-> Array<Lenders>{
    // Setup database connection and save to context.
    var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName2)
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;

    // Get the data and put it into a variable
    var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)

    return results as Array<Lenders>
}


// Reads User's comments on given data.
func readUserCommentsData(lenderId:String)-> Array<LenderUserComments>{

    // Setup database connection and save to context.
    var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: entityName)
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "lenderId = %@", lenderId)

    // Get the data and put it into a variable
    var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)

    return results as Array<LenderUserComments>
}

....

}
```

Added at the request of the a commenter.

```
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext {

        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator

            _managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
            _managedObjectContext!.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator


    return _managedObjectContext!
}
```

---

**Solution**  :I replaced the managedObjectContext variable in AppDelegate.swift.  Credits to Hashmat Khalil for providing the core of the solution.  The below works like a charm.

```
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext {

    if (_managedObjectContext != nil)
    {
        return _managedObjectContext!; // making sure you don't reinitialise
    }
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator

    _managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
    _managedObjectContext!.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator


    return _managedObjectContext!
}
```

Comment: can you show the code for core data reading lender data?

Comment: I have added the class and methods being called above.

Comment: and how do you initialize managedObjectContext? can you post that too? the one in you app delegate.

Comment: Thanks Hashmat,
The manageObjectContext is being initialized in the LendersModel class.  Then once the data has been retrieved, it is passed to the caller as an Array.

As a result, I don't have to instantiate manageObjectContext at the caller level.

Comment: how do you initialize it? on which concurrency it has been configured?

Comment: I am not sure how to answer your question as the code I have added above should provide answers to both your questions.

Comment: one last try otherwise i won't able to answer. go to your app delegate and find property and method which has managedObjectContext or _managedObjectContext in it and post it.

Comment: I think I have added what you asked for.  Let me know if you need more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so now looking at your code every time you access `appDel.managedObjectContext` you are creating a new instance. when the old instance is gone you won't be able to access the data as well and you have to refetch everything. so make sure that you use only one instance. and it would be better for GUI context to have main concurrency.

```
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext {

   if (_managedObjectContext)
    {
        return _managedObjectContext; // making sure you don't reinitialise 
    }
        let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator

            _managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.MainQueueConcurrencyType)
            _managedObjectContext!.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator


    return _managedObjectContext!
}
```

that's it.

Comment: Thanks much Hashmat!  I appreciate your patience.  I will apply your solution and get back with you asap.

Comment: also make sure that you dont reinitialise persistentStoreCoordinator as well as the NSManagedObjectModel.

Comment: With minor modification this worked like a charm. I will posted the modifications to the original question.  Thanks, that makes perfect sense now.